# Setup ASP.NET MVC Wildcard handler on IIS 6 by Command Line

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6

Does anyone know how to setup ASP.NET MVC wildcard handler (ISAPI) as desribed on [ASP MVC on IIS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184990/asp-mvc-on-iis6), by command line only?